# jQuery .data() only displays "undefined" by calling the alert

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to get the value of a data attribute for each node inside a loop. In my example below I need to figure out if the attribute "data-langlabels" contains more than one value, but I may not access it. Do you have any idea what my problem is?

Here's the HTML-Code:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-link="aaa.pdf" data-toggle="dropdown" data-langlabels="English">Link 1</a><br />
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-link="bbb.pdf" data-toggle="dropdown" data-langlabels="English,Spanish">Link 2</a><br />
<a class="dropdown-toggle" href="#" data-link="ccc.pdf" data-toggle="dropdown" data-langlabels="English,Spanish,German">Link 3</a><br />
```

*Javascript part:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var findTarget = $('a').data('toggle');
    if (findTarget === 'dropdown') {
        $('a.dropdown-toggle').each(function() {
            var ieLanguages = $(this).data('langlabels');
            alert('ieLanguages: ' + JSON.stringify(ieLanguages, null, 4));

            if (ieLanguages.indexOf(',') > -1) {
                console.log('display more languages!');

                var count = 0;
                $(this).on('click', function(event) {
                    if(count<1) {
                        event.preventDefault();
                    }
                    count++;
                });

            } else {
                console.log('display only one language!');
            }
        });
    }
<script>
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/vk69f/) a JSFiddle based on the above.

Comment: Have you tried without `JSON.stringify`?

Comment: The fiddle appears to be working for me.  I get 3 popups showing the values stored in data-langlabels

Comment: The fiddle works for me, I get the alert's of all languages

Comment: it works for me on firefox, chrome and IE 10

Comment: Is your code inside `$(document).ready()`? If not, it may be running before the HTML elements are loaded into the DOM.

Comment: Yes, it is inside the `$(document).ready()`. The fiddle also works for me, but maybe I have a conflict with another script inside my lib *???*.

Comment: @user2425177 +1 for your first post, I've seen worst! which lib do you have? make a fiddle with them maybe and try